# select2 initialize with selected value on postback

Tags: jquery, ajax, select, initialization

I'm using an ajax get to populate values in a select2 single-select.

The select2 is initalized like so (jQuery):

```
    $("#domain").select2({
    placeholder: "Placeholder text",
    allowClear: true,
    multiple: false,
    ajax: {
        url: "/json/domain",
        dataType: "json",
        data: function(term, page) {
            return {
                q: term,
            };
        },
        results: function(data, page) {
            return data;
        }
    }
```

This is an example of the response:

```
{"results":[{"id":"1234","text":"Name"}]}
```

Once a value is selected, select2 updates a hidden input with the id and displays "Name" in a span.

The select2 is part of a POST that requests a bunch of data based on selected values.

So on the postback, the selected value "Name" is naturally gone from the DOM (while "id" being retained in the hidden input).

Is there any way to initialize select2 after the postback with the selected value pre-submit (displaying the placeholder pre-postback)?

Looking around here on SO and other places, I've tried something like this:

```
    $("#domain").select2({
    placeholder: "Placeholder text",
    allowClear: true,
    multiple: false,
    ajax: {
        url: "/json/domain",
        dataType: "json",
        data: function(term, page) {
            return {
                q: term
            };
        },
        results: function(data, page) {
            return {results: data};
        }               
    },
    initSelection: function(element, callback) {
        var id = $('#domain').val();
        if(id !== "") {
            $.ajax("/json/domain", {
                dataType: "json"
            }).done(function(data) {
                callback(function(data) { callback(data); });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

This initializes but returns "undefined". I'm guessing it's because data is not passed to the initSelection...

Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine, except this

```
initSelection: function(element, callback) {
    var id = $('#domain').val();
    if(id !== "") {
        $.ajax("/json/domain", {
            dataType: "json"
        }).done(function(data) {
            callback(function(data) { callback(data); });
        });
    }
}
```

Shouldn't it be

```
initSelection: function(element, callback) {
    var id = $('#domain').val();
    if(id !== "") {
        $.ajax("/json/domain", {
            dataType: "json"
        }).done(function(data) {
            callback(data); // here
        });
    }
}
```

As long as the `data` in the following format

```
[{id: 'this', text: 'this'}]
```

Comment: This again returns `undefined` in the input (also on initial pageload, not after submit). The ajax is still working fine and returning data in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong, but the initSelection is a Select2 3.5.2, option.

In Select2 4.0

> This is now handled by the data adapter in the current method, which
>   allows Select2 to convert the currently selected values into data
>   objects that can be displayed.